# Efficiency NSString vs NSInteger/int - only for textual representation

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, nsinteger

I'd like to know if it would make any sense to cast/convert a number, parsed from a csv file, e.g. customer id, to a NSString?
Or maybe better a simple int? As I'm quite new to obj-c, I'm not really sure, wether to consistently use the NSxyz types, or use what I'm used to, coming from Java/C/C++.

Actually the value only is stored in a variable, and then loaded into some textfields (which again would imply a conversion back to NSString I guess?).

Would there be any benefit in less memory being used? Let's assume the ids had 6 digits, parsing roughly 10'000-100'000 customers. Same would apply to smaller numbers, e.g. the addresses street number.

Comment: The ids are not numbers. They happen to be numeric but they are strings. Keep them as strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a `string`, `1 letter == 1 byte`, so if you have 6 digits, you are occupying `6 bytes`.

An `int` instead takes generally `2 (short), 3 or 4 (long) bytes`. It can arrive also to `8 bytes` with an `int_64`. But, you are limited because for example in the *2 byte case* (16 bit) you can consider *2^16* numbers.

In your case you could use an `int`, but i would use an `NSString`, also because you need it in your `textfield`.

An `NSInteger` is an `int`. An `NSUInteger` is an `unsigned int`.

An `NSNumber` is an Object (so no primitive) which can store an `int`, a `float`, a `double` or a `boolean`. So you can store many type of primitive in this type of variable and then use the appropriate:

```
[number floatValue];
[number boolValue];
...
```

Comment: "1 letter = 1 byte" is only true for some letters in some encodings.

Comment: sure. But we are in super-base modality. Don't you see? :) And also it is better say: is not true for some letters in some encodings.

Comment: OK, will stick to NSStrings then. And thanks for the "super-base modality", made me smile haha :)

Comment: 1 letter does not necessarily take up 1 byte. It depends on encoding, composition and the represented character.

Comment: One letter in an NSString is often 1, sometimes 2 bytes. However, an NSString object on its own uses a considerable amount of memory. The NSString* alone uses as much memory as an NSInteger.

Comment: There are so many things wrong about this. For example, an NSInteger is either an int or a long, with 32 or 64 bits. The big advantage of using NSInteger instead of NSString to store an integer is that you _know_ the value is an integer and not for example the string "bla bla bla".